# I need a fix for the structure of my binary tree (python)

Tags: python, binary-tree

Hi i am not getting the output i want.
The inorder traversal is supposed to yield: MAFXUEN
The preorder traversel is supposed to yield: EXAMFUN

```
class Node:
   def init(self, data):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.data = data
# Insert Node
   def insert(self, data):
      if self.data:
         if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
               self.left = Node(data)
            else:
               self.left.insert(data)
         elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
               self.right = Node(data)
            else:
               self.right.insert(data)
      else:
         self.data = data
# Print the Tree
   def PrintTree(self):
      if self.left:
         self.left.PrintTree()
      print( self.data),
      if self.right:
         self.right.PrintTree()
# Inorder traversal
# Left -> Root -> Right
   def inorderTraversal(self, root):
      res = []
      if root:
         res = self.inorderTraversal(root.left)
         res.append(root.data)
         res = res + self.inorderTraversal(root.right)
      return res

   def PreorderTraversal(self, root):
       res = []
       if root:
           res.append(root.data)
           res = res + self.PreorderTraversal(root.left)
           res = res + self.PreorderTraversal(root.right)
       return res


root = Node('E')
root.insert('X')
root.insert('A')
root.insert('M')
root.insert('F')
root.insert('U')
root.insert('N')
print('In-Order:\t', root.inorderTraversal(root))
print('Pre-Order:\t', root.PreorderTraversal(root))
```

Instead the output is  In-Order:     ['A', 'E', 'F', 'M', 'N', 'U', 'X']
Pre-Order:     ['E', 'A', 'X', 'M', 'F', 'U', 'N']

Process finished with exit code 0

I am fairly new to python so I have limited knowledge in what i can do to resolve this. Luckily I am a visual learner so if anyone has a fix i can study it and use it in the future!

Comment: the code seems good. I can't figure out what else you would be calling "pre-order traversal": and "in order traversal" your algorithm is pretty explicit in what it does in both cases.

Comment: @jsbueno It was mainly due to a previous exam question that im using to prep for end year exams. Though I think i did it right and that the output they wanted was a bit illogical. But NOW i want to know how i can do it if neccesary if its possible.